# Mudar de string para int c++

Tags: c++

Seguinte, estou fazendo uma função que receba a data dessa forma "XX/XX/XXXX" mas tenho que realizar verificações como dia, mes, ano bissexto, essas coisas, e estou utilizando o formato dela em string por conta das barras. Então pensei em transformar a string em int, porem só consegui com os dois primeiros valores, como mostrado abaixo:

```
void validar_DATA()throw (invalid_argument){
   string num= "20/09/2020"; 
   int dia,mes,ano;
   stringstream aux;

   aux << num << endl;
   aux >> dia;

}
```

Se for imprimir dia, sai os dois primeiros valores(20), mas como eu faria para pegar o MES e o ANO? Da forma que eu fiz, ao ler a string para tranformar em int, quando chegar em algum caractere que não é numero, no caso mostrado aqui é a '/', ele para de ler, fazendo só os dois antes dela ser transformado em int. Tem alguma forma de lê depois da barra? Colocar algum ponteiro para marcar onde parou e continuar a partir da '/' ?

Eu pensei em concatenar também, porém nao sei concatenar int.

Answer (score 0):

Como vc tem um formato de datas fixo ("DD/MM/AAAA"), acredito que essa seja a solução mais simples.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string data = "20/09/2020";
    std::string dia_str = data.substr(0, 2);
    std::string mes_str = data.substr(3, 2);
    std::string ano_str = data.substr(6, 4);

    int dia = std::atoi(dia_str.c_str());
    int mes = std::atoi(mes_str.c_str());
    int ano = std::atoi(ano_str.c_str());

    std::cout << dia << "/" << mes  << "/" << ano;
}
```